# When should I update the cloud database, whenever user interacts with frontend?

Tags: reactjs, server, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I want to what's the best way to update the frontend (`React` and `ApolloClient`) as well as backend server (`ApolloServer`) to keep data synced between them when user interacts with the frontend and updates something. I think of two ways:

1. Only update the state of component *to get instantaneous updates on the frontend side* and updating the cloud database by calling `fetch` in lifecycle method `componentWillUnmount`. But, as I am using `ApolloClient`, I can use `useMutation` hook to update backend. But how can I use that in `componentWillUnmount`.
2. This one is the conventional one in which we update the frontend and backend both simultaneously. But I think this might affect the user interaction, since backend operation might take too long to respond.

What'd you think? Any suggestions?

Comment: You shouldn't trust the ```componentWillUnmount``` lifecycle to save your data. Imagine a scenario, when user changes some data in your front end and then closes the whole browser. The component would not unmount in that case.
You can have a save button and make user save the data manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @szchocik already pointed out in the comments, relying on `componentWillUnmount` is not a good idea because the method may not necessarily be called. You should make your request to the backend whenever the user expects the data to be saved (for example, when completing a form and hitting a "save" button or when an input is updated and then loses focus).

If you want a more instantaneous experience for your users when a mutation is executed, you can utilize optimistic updates [as described in the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/performance/optimistic-ui/). Providing an `optimisticResponse` parameter to your `useMutation` hook will allow you to immediately update the client cache (and therefore your UI) without waiting for the server's response.